# Windows Universal - crashes when calling C# runtime component in C++ project

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

Solution contains two projects, one is main project using c++, another project is an runtime component using C#, which is called in main project.

It works ok on Windows 10 Phone if loading on the device by VS Express for Windows10.

But the package for uploading to Windows Store crashes when running on the phone.

The following steps will reproduce the crash:
    (1) created an .appxupload package and unzip it to extract .appx package in it;
    (2) put this .appx package on the phone;
    (3) click .appx file to install app on the phone;
    (4) run the app - it runs ok until instantiate the C# class - app crashes;

Anything I need to do specifically to avoid it? or it's a bug of Microsoft?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you post the error someone would help you...

Comment: Thanks for comment Gusman, there is an exception crashes the app -  "The specified module could not be found". This exception doesn't happen if I load app on the phone using Visual Studio (both debug or release are ok)

Comment: Post the exact error, which module isn't found? the best you can do is to copy the exact error message and add it to your question, without as many info as possible no one will be able to help you. As more info you provide, more easily you will get help.

Comment: Sorry Gusman, this is the only exception info I could get. This exception happens when call the C# runtime component I created from c++ project. So I think the "module" here is this C# runtime component. Sorry I couldn't get further detailed info, because when connected with visual studio, app runs ok, no exception happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer.

I think from the beginning I shouldn't directly install .appxupload package on the phone.

I submitted the .appxupload package (without any change) to Windows Store and then install the app from Store, the app doesn't crash at all. Apparently, .appxupload package is for submitting to Store only - I think Windows Store would do some further process on package after submission?

If you'd like to have a test for your app, always install the .appx package in XXX_Test folder instead of .appxupload.

Answer (score -1):

What about the paths? While in visual studio, the component paths  are working properly, but while loading it from the appx, the paths might not be getting set  properly. So the app is unable to find the necessary components...

Try going through the various directory and file paths in your project dependencies (for both the c++ and c# projects) to list out all the components and their references. Then verify if those references could be found in those paths when running on the phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've checked references and contents in appx package as well. seems all references exist. I also found that the crash happens only when calling C# from C++. if I implement an runtime component with C++ instead of C# - no crash.

Comment: What about the versions of the dlls? Does your C# component have any dependency that is not present on the phone, or has a different version?

Comment: No, this C# component currently only has an empty class file. it doesn't depend on any other components. By the way, the appx in XX_Test folder works fine, only appx in .appxupload crashes.

Comment: That is strange... BTW, do you really need that empty class C# component? 
Try running the appx **from visual studio** in **Release** mode in your device. Does it work same as in the Debug mode? 

Sorry to say, I have never developed windows phone apps, though currently I am doing a Windows Embedded Compact 7 project. So I don't know about the exact steps that a windows phone appx goes through. I am just thinking over the general stuff that happens when you run any program in windows environment...

Comment: You did say that the app runs fine until you try to instantiate the C# component... Can you run the app, then connect VS to the already running app, and try to see what exactly happens when the C# component is being initiated?

Comment: As the app is loaded without visual studio, when connecting already running app with VS, not getting any output. App runs fine with release mode loaded by VS.

Comment: You cannot debug properly if you try to connect VS to already running app **if** the app executable was made in **release** mode. Try building the app in debug mode. Then pack this debug executable into the installer, install this onto the phone and then run that executable. So now you will have a debug executable running on your phone. Then try to connect VS to this running debug executable .

Usually VS has this option of 'Attach to process' and you can attach VS debugger to a running process (As far as windows exe is concerned). So i was thinking along the same lines.

Comment: One question... I seem to remember that VS had settings which sometimes allowed it to step over/skip tiny exceptions and continue execution. Set VS to report about each and every exception and then try loading the app from VS... See if VS reports anything strange now.

Comment: Thanks for your advice PRinCEKtd, I think from the beginning I shouldn't directly install .appxupload package on the phone.

I submitted the .appxupload package (without any change) to Windows Store and then install the app from Store, the app doesn't crash at all. Apparently, .appxupload package is for submitting to Store only - I think Windows Store would do some further process on package after submission?